# Changing font in AlertDialog

Tags: java, android, android-alertdialog

Could someone suggest a way to change font in a dynamically created AlertDialog (in title and body)? I tried in loads of ways, but none of them worked. The code is:

```
public void onClick(View v) {

    new AlertDialog.Builder( c )
    .setTitle( data.eqselect )
    //  .set 
    .setIcon(R.drawable.icon)
    .setMessage(Threads.myData[0] )
    .setNegativeButton( "Close", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            Log.d( "AlertDialog", "Negative" );
        }
    } )
    .show();
}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Instead of setting the text of the alertdialog, you should set a custom view form your layouts. And before you do so, modify your view's font.

```
TextView mycontent = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.yourid);
         mycontent.setTypeface(Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "font.ttf")
```

And to set the view of your alert dialog, call `.setView(mycontent)` instead of `setMessage()`
Although this doesn't change your title as far as I know.

**Update**
I'm seeing you're unable to get what I'm saying, so here's a full example

```
TextView content = new TextView(this);
         content.setText("on another font");
         content.setTypeface(Typeface.SANS_SERIF);

//Use the first example, if your using a xml generated view

     AlertDialog.Builder myalert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
         myalert.setTitle("Your title");
         myalert.setView(content);
         myalert.setNeutralButton("Close dialog", null);
         myalert.setCancelable(true);
         myalert.show();
```

This is using a TextView that we've just created, and it won't have margins or such. If you use a readily created one form your layout files, you'd be able to customize all those settings, although you can do that for this example to in code.

Of course, replace the font with the one you want..
A sample TextView from xml could be:

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/yourid"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="8dp"
        android:text="your content" />
```

Comment: would it pop out in the same way?

Comment: Sure, you'r just telling him to use a custom view instead of the default one. Give it a try

Comment: But it won't pop out as an alert dialog which don't take whole screen and the layout would

Comment: Either you're not understanding the answer, or I'm not understanding the question. Read update

Comment: Where could I find an example of view layout I need to make? Cause I don't understand how it would work

Comment: Thanks, you saved me! I was confused by this part findViewById(R.id.yourid)

Comment: As I said, you can either use a created id that's present in your R.id or create one in code, both options covered in my answer. Glad I could help